# How to connect to imap via ssh in PHP

Tags: php, ssh, imap

I am trying to communicate with imap via ssh in PHP.
The following code demonstrates how I connect to imap via ssh:

```
$ssh_conn = ssh2_connect($sshIP, $sshPORT);
ssh2_auth_password($ssh_conn, $sshUSERNAME, $sshPASSWORD);
$stream = ssh2_tunnel($c, $imapSERVER, $imapPORT);
```

And seems everything is ok, I get connected to imap via ssh. No errors, and I have resource in $stream.

Then I try to write LOGIN command to stream, like this:

```
fwrite($stream, "A1 LOGIN username password\r\n");
```

Problem is that server doesn't response anything.

I try to get response like this:

```
while (true) {
     echo fread($stream, 4096);
}
```

Don't worry about codes for writing and reading data to imap server, this I have written just for example. This is not important here. The problem is that I don't get any response from imap. Always empty string.

I am sure, writing and reading methods work well, because I use big HORDE library https://dev.horde.org/imap_client/, and when I use stream of SOCKS5 or HTTPS - it work well!

Also I tried different SSH servers - not success.

So, where might be a problem ? 
Also the next information may be useful:
I get different information when using stream_get_meta_data() for ssh and socks5 stream.

SSH:

```
array(8) {
  ["exit_status"]=>
  int(0)
  ["timed_out"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["blocked"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["eof"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["stream_type"]=>
  string(12) "SSH2 Channel"
  ["mode"]=>
  string(2) "r+"
  ["unread_bytes"]=>
  int(0)
  ["seekable"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

SOCKS5:

```
array(8) {
  ["crypto"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["protocol"]=>
    string(7) "TLSv1.2"
    ["cipher_name"]=>
    string(27) "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"
    ["cipher_bits"]=>
    int(128)
    ["cipher_version"]=>
    string(7) "TLSv1.2"
  }
  ["timed_out"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["blocked"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["eof"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["stream_type"]=>
  string(14) "tcp_socket/ssl"
  ["mode"]=>
  string(2) "r+"
  ["unread_bytes"]=>
  int(0)
  ["seekable"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Also I notified important thing, it is working if I use port 143 for imap server. And doesn't work if I use port 993. But 143 is not ssl. Therefore I can't even use LOGIN command. I think cause touches with ssl. But how to set ssl for ssh tunnel..... ?

Comment: Do you need to terminate the commands with a new line?

Comment: Do you mean "\r\n" in writing command? I am sure, this can't be the cause. Coz I use big libriry for commands, it is implemented well there

Comment: Sorry for the silly question... But, why don't you use PHP IMAP functions ? (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) ?

Comment: MarcoS, because I need imap via proxy, also custom library is more quickly and powerful

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: cmbuckley, https://dev.horde.org/imap_client/ this one